# How do I get rid of the comma at the end of this Javascript array that is populated using Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using Razor to insert items into a Javascript array.  It's working as intended using the code below.  However, it results in one extra comma at the end of the array.  Can someone suggest a way to prevent this from happening?

```
graphByMonth = new Array(

@foreach (var cost in Model.Cost) {
    <text>
    [@cost.CPM, '@cost.EndDate'],
    </text>
    }
);
```

Comment: Why not serialize it to a JSON array server-side? Wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: just leave it, js is ok with one comma at the end of the array

Comment: @ChuckNorris the comma is causing problems with some other scripts I have that consume the array.  that's why i'm trying to eliminate it.

Comment: @RPM1984 I was planning on doing that.  But I was stumped on this and thought surely there must be a simple way to eliminate that darn comma.  Didn't want to give up on it so easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use any string concatenations when dealing with javascript. If you want to pass some server side model to a javascript variable you could JSON serialize it like this to ensure that dangerous characters are properly escaped:

```
var graphByMonth = @Json.Encode(Model.Cost.Select(cost => new {
    cpm = cost.CPM, endDate = cost.EndDate
}));
```

which will render as:

```
var graphByMonth = [
    { cost: '1', endDate: 'date 1' },
    { cost: '2', endDate: 'date 2' },
    { cost: '3', endDate: 'date 3' }
];
```

Using `Json.Encode` you ensure that the values are properly encoded and you won't have any broken syntax which is what you will get if you ever try to manually do this by using some string concatenations, foreach loops or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that error.  I have deleted my answer as this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: I agree. the problem isn't the js, the problem is the server for-loop appending the additional comma.